# Unable to import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark, streaming

The following import is failing to compile in SBT

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._

[error] /home/hduser/workspace/TweetStream/src/main/scala/TweetStream.scala:8: object twitter is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming
[error] import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
[error]
```

And the following subsequently as well

```
val tweetStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2).map(gson.toJson(_))


[error] /home/hduser/workspace/TweetStream/src/main/scala/TweetStream.scala:36: not found: value TwitterUtils
[error]     val tweetStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2).map(gson.toJson(_))
[error]                       ^
                                 ^
```

The build.sbt is the following passes all dependency resolution

```
name := "TweetStream"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "4.0.4"
```

Have I added the wrong dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the build.sbt ...

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "TweetStream",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("TweetStream")        
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.5.2",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.11" % "1.5.2",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.7",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "3.0.3",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "3.0.3"
)

// META-INF discarding
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
   {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
   }
}
```

And the assembly.sbt in the project subfolder

`addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add the following dependency :

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-twitter_2.11
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.11" % "1.5.2"
```

PS: The other dependencies Scala version might cause you some problems. You ought specifying _2.11 for your other spark dependencies.

Comment: Thanks so much Eliasah. 

The import issue is gone, but 

`val tweetStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2).map(gson.toJson(_))

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/twitter/TwitterUtils$`

still remains. And ideas, please.

Thanks again.

Comment: that's because you have to build an uber-jar. with sbt assembly per example

Comment: @Maz did you solve your issue ? if so, please accept the answer to close it ! Thanks

Comment: Yes, it has Thanks so much.